# How to implement ajax Django comment?

Tags: ajax, django, forms, web, comments

What I am doing is following.
post_detail.html

```
<div class="comment_form">
    <form id="comment_form" method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include "myblog/post_comment.html" %}
        <button id="add_comment" type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" >Comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Post detail view

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Add comment to post

```
def add_comment_post(request, slug):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():

            lst_com = form.save(commit=False)
            lst_com.post = post

            x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
            if x_forwarded_for:
                ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
            else:
                ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            lst_com.ip_address = ip
            lst_com.published_date = timezone.now()
            lst_com.save()

    return render_to_response('myblog/post_comment.html', {'form': form }, RequestContext(request))
```

ajax request_to_add_comment_post

```
$('#add_comment').click(function() {
        $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comment/",
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
        success: addSucsess,
        dataType: 'html'
      });
});
```

function addSucsess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

```
$('#comment_form').html(data);
```

Now, my problem here is when add_comment_post return "render_to_response", post_detail.view is called again. How to solve this? What is the correct solution ?

Comment: With HTML response, there is no sense of ajax.

Comment: there is is ajax request in javascript file .

Comment: And anothor questions why post_detail is called after ajax request ?